# Visual Studio 2015 - an item with same key has been added

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, sitefinity

I recently installed Visual Studio 2015 update 3 (KB3095681). After installing update 3, I'm getting an error of `An item with same key has already been added.`

I checked if the issue was in my project, but no it was not in my project. I created a new mvc project when I'm trying to run the application it gives me the same error.

Did anyone face this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue. Microsoft has released a new windows update which contains .net frame work 4.7. I was also having sitefinity projects where sitefinity was not compatible with 4.7 framework, which caused this issue. I rolled back all the windows updates which was done and all my projects are up and running.

Comment: Yeah, there are issues with Windows 10 Creative update which I think have been resolved in recent Sitefinity hotfixes

Comment: Yup. but that requires upgrading your project to hotfixes, which I can't do because of lots of custom functionality. That's the reason I have rolled back the update.